# swift list -p variable not setting

Tags: bash, openstack, openstack-swift

I'm using swift CLI and trying to download multiple objects from a container.

I can do this as such

```
for i in `swift list container -p object/201505`; do swift download container $i; done
```

the problem is I have multiple objects I need to search for and download all that match. I've tried doing it in a small script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read objects;
SAMPLE=$(swift list container objects);
do
for i in $SAMPLE; do `swift download container $i`; done
done < samples_list
```

But I am always greeted with the following.

```
Usage: swift [options] list [options] [container]
    Lists the containers for the account or the objects for a container. -p or
    --prefix is an option that will only list items beginning with that prefix.
    -d or --delimiter is option (for container listings only) that will roll up
    items with the given delimiter (see Cloud Files general documentation for
    what this means).
```

Are my variables not being read? How can I download only the files that have the correct prefix as I set?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know `swift`, but I think you want

```
#!/bin/bash

while read objects; do
  swift list container "$objects" | while read i; do
    swift download container "$i"
  done
done < samples_list
```

I am assuming `swift list` writes one item per line in its output.

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for the fast response. I have edited the script to reflect your changes and it gives the same error.  I'll do the needful and investigate more of it being openstack swift issue.